# Problema con map

Tags: java, hashmap

Tengo un problema, quiero realizar un programa de login de usuario con la interfaces Map, pero en mi clase "contraseña" no me deja usar el metodo put para empezar a realizar el programa`import java.util.*;

```
public class Main{


  public static void main(String[] args)
    {




    System.out.println("     COMISION LALO S.A DE C.V");

    System.out.println("opcion 1: crear usuario. \nopcion 2: cargar usuario");






    }}

 class Contraseña {
    Map <String,String>a=new HashMap <String,String>();


    private void estableceUsuarioContraseña( String usuario,String contraseña){


    }


 }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con el siguiente Fragmento de codigo :

```
//Declaramos e instanciamos un Map con clave String y value String
Map<String,String> mapa = new HashMap<>();


private void estableceUsuarioContraseña( String usuario,String contraseña)
{
    mapa.put(usuario, contraseña);
}
```

Espero te sirva 
Saludos.